# nvme ssd won't show up on ubuntu install

Tags: boot, acpi, nvme

**Hello dear forum user, I came in a great need.**

I use ubuntu for almost 10 years for now, until now I always was able to fix, if a problem occured,
but this really stopped me now.

Long story short, i bought a new **Acer a315-23-A8DS** for my Mum, she uses ubuntu on her current system, so I wanted to make it the same for her.

ryzen athlon 3020e. + wd sn520  120gb nvme ssd.

Windows worsk fine on the machine, so I am preatty sure the machine has no porblem.

To recap:

- ssd in ahci mode (bios won't even gives option to change it)
- secure boot off
- fastboot off
- [uefi fresly updated to the latest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUe7I.jpg)
- [nvme ssd firmware already up to date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DblL.jpg)
- tried installers: 20.04 , 20,10 also mint 20.04

**The Ubuntu install media boots sucsesfully, but can't find the nvme ssd.**

dmesg gives the following error

[dmesg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YN0u.jpg)

The complete dmesg:
https://pastebin.com/fNgAjv2d

From this I think the problem is somwhere in the communication or power states.

I found similar problems on the net, most notably on the wd forum.

https://community.wd.com/t/linux-support-for-wd-black-nvme-2018/225446/13

I tried to add in grub  **nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500,**
I also tried with **5000, 5200, 14000** latency.

[If I done it right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oyEw.jpg)

But the problem still remained.

I also tried to add **acpi=off**, with this the install media freezed out on boot, I didn't got into the lvie-cd.

Furthermore: I have my own nvme ssd in my rig,so i swaped it from my pc  to test it like that.

with the nvme ssd from the acer in my desktop, the install media:
both ubuntu install media freeze out while loading in.
mint istall starts, but fails while formating the drive.

**With my desktop ssd in the acer, all install media freeze out.**

I have an ubuntu on that drive with luks, it loads until it get's to the lusk password, but when I enter it, can't find the lvm group for it.

This part where I can't install onto a different drive, bugs me the most.

I am not 100% sure if the problem is the drive itself, or some controller on the board.

It has a place for a sata drive, butl lacs the sata zif cable  and the cage. My plan B is to order a cable from e-bay and try it with a sata drive, but at this point I am not sure that would work, also it would take like 2 months to arrive from china,
and I wanted to give it to my Mom as a christmas present. (guess i will have to give her windows)

Pardon me, if I am not clear, this is my first post here.

Comment: does the second answer for this question help (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277405/problems-installing-ubuntu-on-acer-laptop)

Comment: Can you try installing an Ubuntu LTS and see if it recognises the SSD please? I know that's now an answer but it might tell other experts something useful.