# How install Ubuntu 22.04 on Acer 315-23?

Tags: boot, acer

I have tried as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277405) (nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500 ... etc.).

Problems:

- Shift key no longer gives access to the boot menu, so I can't complete it.
- Keyboard and mouse freeze 10-15 seconds after boot.
- During boot I got "critical medium errors". (How to see them again?)

I have chosen the erase disk install Ubuntu option.

Comment: Not sure if you still need that setting or not. With UEFI boot, grub menu is by using escape key after vendor logo, but before grub menu normally would appear. If UEFI fast boot on in UEFI settings, you may not have time to press any key. Many Acer need Shift S for more settings. Acer Swift 5 (2019) ctrl-s  in UEFI required to be able to change to AHCI mode.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217061/installation-on-acer-swift-5-freezes-no-partitions-shown
Did you verify download of ISO?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @olfred

Now, as "Acer" apears on screen it says in the upper left corner:

"error: failure reading 0x014fc from hd1" or

"error: failure reading 0x014fc from hd0" depending on which usb-installation-key I use.

"Shift" no longer gets me to the sentence with "quiet splash" but to "GNU GRUB version 2.06" at the top center.
I don't know how to escape from there. I tried Esc, ctrl + x, Enter, F10.
No I didn't verify ISO, mouse and keyboard is dead.

Comment: Would this be a solution to my problems? :https://linuxhint.com/fix-broken-ubuntu-22-04-without-reinstalling/

Comment: Link seems to be more about fixing an install. You have issue with drive. Search seems to indicate failing drive, but strange that both drives have same issue. Were they NTFS and hibernated or bitlocker on? Do you have setting in UEFI on locking drive? Is mode ACHI, not RAID.

Comment: NTFS yes. The rest I dont know about. How do i find out ?

Comment: One install succeeded (only with dead keyboard and mouse) with https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277405 but I now can't get to it, because I cant get out of "GNU GRUB version 2.06" . The error message also occurs with no drive (attempt to reinstall).

Comment: Did you set "trust" in UEFI on Ubuntu entry? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256083&p=13203044#post13203044 & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2290594

Answer (score 1):

I installed Ubuntu 23.04.  by:

A) disable secure boot in the uefi.

B) "In the GRUB boot menu, press e to edit startup parameter. Add nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500 after the end of "quiet splash"
Ctrl-x to boot up, the installer should detect this disk in partition step."

Step 2 and 3 here:

[Problems installing Ubuntu on Acer laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277405/problems-installing-ubuntu-on-acer-laptop)

Was not necessary.