# Upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 from 18.04 on Acer Aspire ES1-533

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, uefi, acer

I'm using an Acer Aspire ES1-533 laptop. I already have Ubuntu 18.04 installed and I'm really happy with the OS. Installing 18.04 was a nightmare, but I was able to do it by following this guide https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/hnke1e/guide_installing_ubuntu_on_acer_aspire_es15/

However trying to install 20.04 or 22.04 has proven to be impossible. I have already tried the recommendations in this thread [Problems installing Ubuntu on Acer laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277405/problems-installing-ubuntu-on-acer-laptop) to no avail. Could you guys help me please? I'm very new to Linux, but Ubuntu 18.04 isn't supported anymore and I'd like to keep using it. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/862946/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-es1-533#876153   could work (even though it is 6y6m old.

Comment: @Rinzwind sadly it didn't work as Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 have the try and install Ubuntu options in the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to Ubuntu Pro.

It's free, it's supported for five more years, and it bypasses the problem with your locked UEFI.

Of course, you will be using 2018-vintage applications on that 2018-vintage OS. You can sometimes get around that limitation by using Snap-based software.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll subscribe. I thought you had to pay, but now that you mention it is free, there's no reason not to. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After some search I managed to solve my problem with the following steps:

1. Download the iso's for Ubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu 18.04. Create a bootable pen drive for both.
2. Boot the 22.04 pen drive and press `E` on the grub option `Try ubuntu without installing`.
3. Add `acpi=off nomodeset` after `/casper/vmlinuz` and press F10.

   - Wifi will not work, the touchpad might have a weird behavior and the battery status will not show up, so make sure to plug the charger (after installation these problems won't exist).
4. On terminal run the command and follow the installation steps:

```
sudo ubiquity -b
```

5. Turn off the computer by pressing the power button and boot the 18.04 live cd.
6. On terminal, mount the newly installed system on `/mnt` :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo mkdir /mnt/boot/efi
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
```

- Where `sda2` is the root partition and `sda1` is the EFI system partition

7. Load efivars:

```
sudo modprobe efivars
```

8. Reinstall grub:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
sudo grub-install --no-nvram --root-directory=/mnt
```

9. Change root to `/mnt` and update grub:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
update-grub
```

10. Remove the package `secureboot-db` :

```
apt remove secureboot-db
apt-mark hold secureboot-db
```

11. Move and rename the installed bootloader:

```
cd /boot/efi/EFI
cp -R ubuntu/* BOOT/
cd BOOT
cp grubx64.efi bootx64.efi
```

12. Turn off the computer and boot the installed system, then run:

```
echo "grub-efi-amd64 grub2/force_efi_extra_removable boolean true" | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo update-grub
```

13. Reboot the system.

References:

- https://github.com/facila/Linux-on-acer
- [Unable to install Ubuntu on Acer Aspire ES1-533](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862946/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-es1-533)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/hnke1e/guide_installing_ubuntu_on_acer_aspire_es15/